# Avoid showing https requests from packet sniffing

Tags: ssl-certificate, packet-sniffers, packet-capture, charles-proxy, man-in-the-middle

I have an android app with few apis that has SSL. When i try to do packet sniffing using Fiddler2 or charles proxy after installing a trusted certificate on my device, I've been able to see all HTTPS calls. 
I made a few tests in other apps to see if its normal and found some of them won't show or connect to the ssl request. How can i avoid being showing my APIS on packet sniffing. I am using lets encrypt on my domain for ssl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible and it also shouldn't be necessary.

It is impossible to tell whether a device along the path between client and server is sniffing packets. Thus you will not be able to kill the connection based on whether someone is sniffing somewhere. This is the equivalent of looking at a downloaded file on your computer and wondering how many other copies there are in the world. Neither the file nor your receipt thereof stores this data.

It should also not be necessary as HTTPS is immune to MITM provided you are not a state-level actor. This is unless you have access to the client, in which case you can add your MITM as a trusted CA. For more info on HTTPS and MITM attacks, you should take a look at Kazakhstan's [past attempt at it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazakhstan_man-in-the-middle_attack)

Comment: 1. “I read somewhere” doesn’t cut it on Stack Overflow. Google it and post a link instead. 2. Do more reading on what TLS is and how it’s set up as that will help you.